# Getting the correct instance of view pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am displaying 1 imageView & 1 textView in view pager by using this code

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {

        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;
        tv=(TextView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);       

        tv.setText(ItemListApplication.names.get(position).getDesc());

        pos = position; // saved the current position in pos

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override

            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }
```

I want to post that image & text on facebook from button in ActionBar, but using `pos=position` in `instantiateItem()` I sometimes get the wrong position(means different image).

How can I get the correct position so that the correct data can be posted. Also I am not using fragments.

I hope the problem is clear !

Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position` param in `instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position)` does not represent the currently visible item of ViewPager.

View pager caches one item to the left and to the right of currently visible item. For example, if the current index of ViewPager is at [5], then the view pager already instantiated one item to the left and right of [5]. Hence, it cached [4][5][6].

If the current index of ViewPager is at [5], and if you navigate to the right, current index will become [6]. And item [7] will be instantiated, now `position` param in `instantiateItem()` will be 7. And it cached [5][6][7].

If the current index of ViewPager is at [5], and if you navigate to the left, current index will become [4]. And item [3] will be instantiated, now `position` param in `instantiateItem()` will be 3.  And it cached [3][4][5].

To get the current index of the ViewPager use this from any point of your activity:

```
int currentPostion= mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

However, getCurrentItem() returns 0 if the view pager already reached the first and the last index. You may need to override `onPageSelected()` of ViewPager's `PageChangeListener` as shown below.

```
int pos;//to track the current page
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        pos=position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Iteired this, but this method fails for the first & last pager !